# Is it possible to combine Convolution Matrices to apply several transformations at once?

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix, transformation, convolution

Theoretically it should be possible to combine transformation or color matrices, through addition or multiplication (I'm lame when it comes to such math). Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is! In Flash, the convolution matrices are defined in the [flash.geom](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/package-detail.html) package. The transformation matrix is a `Matrix` and the color matrix is a `ColorTransform`. Both implement a `concat` function letting you multiply the effects of another matrix.

```
var a:Matrix = new Matrix();
a.translate(60, 40);

var b:Matrix = new Matrix();
b.rotate(60);

a.concat(b); // Matrix a now translates and rotates whatever it convolutes.
```

Comment: But do you know what's an actual logic behind this? I would like to port it to let's say JavaScript?

Comment: It is purely matrix multiplication, so any article on matrix multiplication will show you how to do it. You could also consider asking a question in http://math.stackexchange.com/. Rolling your own implementation of a matrix in code can be a bit tricky though. Consider using a library, like http://sylvester.jcoglan.com/